# Adding child SKNode to existing SKNode changes the touch area

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I'm create a SKNode to the scene and logging touch events on each individual SKNode. I can add as many as I want and the touches work as expected, if I touch the node and only the visible node do I see the log messages. Now, if I add another SKShapeNode to any of the previous SKNode's the touch area expands to be more of a rectangle and now I see the log message even if I touch outside the origin SKNode.

The first picture shows the original touch area of the SKNode and the second is the new touch area after adding a child SKShapeNode to that SKNode. The SKShapeNode being added is 20x20 so it fits within the 20x100 bar.

The problem is I now get multiple touch events when touching the other bars since they overlap. Is there any way around this?

[image: Touch area shown in blue for that SKNode]
[image: New touch area after adding a child SKShapeNode]

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using separate graphics for each angle of your line. Instead try using the same graphic with your line at 0 degrees and then using the [zRotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zRotation) to angle it. I have not tried this myself but I think it will fix your issue.

Alternately try using [containsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/containsPoint:) for your touch recognition in the touchesBegan method. You can check if the touch is within any of the nodes and process accordingly.

Comment: Rotating a node changes its bounding box in a way consistent with what the OP is seeing